# Unable to unpartition main hard drive

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, core-storage, fusion-drive

I have a late 2013 27 inch iMac with a 3 TB Fusion Drive with macOS Sierra installed.

I partitioned my drive right down the middle, so 1.5 TB on either side.

When I went into Disk Utility mode to unpartition it, there was no minus sign to do so.
I've tried resizing it, booting in Recovery Mode and erasing and restoring the whole drive and nothing works.

I'm currently trying Internet Recovery Mode while unmounting with the terminal but when my "diskutil list" shows up with 19 drives!

Not sure where all these are from but I just want my drive back to the whole 3 TB drive if possible.

I've tried `diskutil unmountDisk` command as well as Force unmount... it will unmount a few of them, but then crash after I force one that doesn't unmount regularly...

And yes, if you haven't guessed it, I am completely new to all this terminal stuff

[image: yes, it is an actual "screenshot"]...[image]

Comment: Thank you Klanomath, however when doing that I am getting: Error -69771: Target disk is too small for this operation

Comment: I just tried 3000g and it seems to be processing... would it cause issues if it was too small?

Comment: 3106g seems to be the magic number however, when I do the diskutil list command it is still showing 19 disks. two of them internal, physical, two internal, virtual, and 15 "(disk image)"     /rev/disk 18 (internal, Physical) shows 3TB and /rev/disk19 (internal, virtual) shows 3.1 TB

Comment: how do I get rid of those disks? or should I? the unmount command doesn't seem to actually remove them. when run diskutil unmountDisk /   some say they unmount successfully, but when I exit terminal and reopen, run the list, they show back up

Comment: You don't have to ged rid of those disks. Most of them belong to Internet Recovery Mode and are RAM disks only. disk0 is your ssd and disk18 your hdd which constitute the fusion drive. disk19 is the resulting lv.

Comment: I was able to reinstall mac OS Sierra on the full 3tb drive, and it seems to be running a lot faster without issue. So I think that resolved my issue. Thank you very much klanomath! your time and knowledge are truly appreciated!